# Twin primes sums conjecture

Tags: conjectures, twin-primes

I have found an interesting conjecture between twin primes sums. I don't know if it is already described by someone else. I have checked in internet, but I didn't find any mention of such conjecture.

Could you please tell me if the following conjecture is well known for mathematicians or not?

Let's take twin prime pair 11 and 13 and do the sum:

*11+13=24*

Now find out sums of two prime numbers which gives the result 24.

*5+19=24*

*7+17=24*

You can see that sums 5+19 and 7+17 contain twin primes 5, 7 and 17, 19. Sum of twin primes 11 + 13 can be written by sum of combinations of twin primes 5, 7 and 17, 19.

Another example: 
Let's take sum of twin prime pair 17, 19:

*17+19=36*

Its sum can be written with using of other twin primes 5, 7 and 29, 31 as:

*5+31=36*

*7+29=36*

We can define twin prime sums conjecture as follow.

Let’s p and q are twin prime numbers; q=p+GAP. For each p+q = a+b = c+d. Where a, b, c, d are prime numbers, where a, c and b, d are prime pairs where c=a+GAP ; d=b-GAP. For twin primes sums conjecture GAP is equal to 2.

Twin prime sums conjecture doesn’t work for prime pairs p, q equals (3, 5), (5, 7), (197, 199), (347, 349).

I have checked the first 100 000 twin primes. The largest checked twin prime pair was 18409199 + 18409201 = 1019 + 36817381 = 1021 + 36817379. It has been found that there are exceptions of p, q for which this conjecture doesn’t work. For sums 3+5; 5+7; 197+199; 347+ 349 it doesn’t exist a, b and c, d which fulfill conjecture.

If twin prime sum conjecture is true then there are unlimited twin prime pairs, because it shows that each twin prime pair sum can be written by sum of combination of smaller and larger twin prime pairs.

For twin primes gap between p,q is equal to 2. I have found that similar conjecture works also for larger even gaps.

*Example for GAP equals 6*

*23+29=52*

We can see that GAP between primes 23 and 29 is equal to 6.  29 – 23 = 6.
Now we will find sums of other primes which have equal sum to 52.

*5+47=52*

*11+41=52*

We have combination of primes 5, 11 and 41, 47. We can see that GAP between those primes is equal to 6, (11 - 5 = 47 - 41 = 6) and is same as the GAP between primes 29 and 23 .

I have also checked this generalized conjecture for primes below 100 000 and even gaps below 100. All of the gaps have few exception pairs p, q for which conjecture doesn’t work, but in major amount of cases conjecture works and for sum of primes with gap we can find another two sums of prime pairs with same gap.

Comment: One thing you might try:  take some even numbers (not the sum of twin primes) and see if you can still express them the way you want.  There are lots of primes and (for small size) there are lots of twin primes.  You might just be seeing some consequences of that.

Comment: Too beautiful to be true but I wish you good luck in your idea, it is not impossible a priori (I think, however, that  great mathematicians have failed to demonstrate the infinity of twin primes). Good luck again, your observation is acute.

Comment: See [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach's_conjecture).

Comment: @Lucian Goldbach conjecture says that every even number can be written by sum of two primes. It doesn't say how these primes should looks like. I don't see relation between this conjecture and Goldbach. If this conjecture is true it doesn't proof the Goldbach's and otherwise if Goldbach is true it doesn't proof this one. I see only relation between this conjecture and twin prime conjecture. If this conjecture is true then there are unlimited twin primes.

Comment: @IvanSas: Goldbach's conjecture stipulates that all numbers $>3$ lie midway between two primes, i.e., $p_{1,2}=n\pm d.$ You set out to investigate the case $d=2.$ Also, for each *n*, *d* can have more than one solution. For the cases where $d=2$ is *one* of the solutions, you have set forth to investigate if such a solution is unique. You have found only a handful of such examples, which is not at all surprising, since the number of solutions for *d* increases as *n* increases.

Comment: @Lucian If there is twin prime couple p+q=n,where n is even number. Is it obvious that it exist also couple a+b=c+d=n where a,c and b,d are twin prime couples? How do you know that twin prime sums should  generate combination of other twin prime sums? As I found there are even few exceptions for p=347, q=349 which doesn't have such twin primes a,b and c,d. If you read the whole post, I have also written about similar relation with larger distance between prime numbers. Example  was for gap 6,  23+29=5+47=11+41=52 and 29-23=47-41=11-5=6. How do you know that this is obvious?

Comment: @IvanSas: They can't both be twin prime couples, not unless $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: @Lucian Sorry for mistake in reply, twin primes couples are a,c and b,d as you can see in main post it is written correctly. If we have 11+13=24 and 5+19=7+17=24 you can see that 5, 7 and 17,19 are twin prime couples. It is not obvious rom Goldbach conjecture that 11+13=5+19=7+17=24 and also 13-11=7-5=19-17=2. How do you know that for sum 11+13 exists equals sums 5+19 and 7+17 where 5, 7 and 17,19 are twin primes?

Comment: @Lucian Everything is about information we possess. Knowing which exact primes is much more information needed than knowing how many primes and this is much more information than knowing that it exist at least one prime. This conjecture returns information that there exists some prime couples with some relations between them. Goldbach's conjecture returns information that it exist at least one prime couple sums for even number. Both conjectures operates on different kind of information, which is not full information of how prime numbers are distributed.

Comment: This conjecture (if true) would only prove that a twin prime pair implies the existence of SMALLER twin prime pairs. It would not show that there are infinite many twin primes.

Comment: Hence this conjecture is weaker than the twin-prime-conjecture and might be easier to prove.

Comment: @Peter This conjecture suggest that for twin prime pair (p,q) exists sum p+q = a+b = c+d where (a,c) and (b,d) are twin prime pairs. 
If such sum exist than (a,c) < (p,q) < (b,d). So for twin prime pair (p,q) exist larger pair (b,d).

For example for twin prime pair (p,q) = (59,61) it can be found larger twin pair (b,d)=(107,109) which mixed with smaller twin pair (a,c)=(13,11)
gives sum equality: 59+61 = 107+13 = 109+11

Comment: @Peter This conjecture says that for twin prime pair (p,q) it can be found SMALLER (a,c) and LARGER (b,d) twin prime pairs where p+q = a+b = c+d. 

If this conjecture is true than twin prime conjecture is also true.

For larger pairs than (347,349) I didn't found any which doesn't have sum pair. In addition when twin primes (p,q) are get larger then they have much more LARGE (b,d) pairs with sum equality.
From this empirical observation it looks that this conjecture might be true. But this is of course not proof.

Comment: @IvanSas If we go to larger numbers the gap between twin-prime-pairs gets quickly larger. $10^5$ is way too small for such patterns. Anyway, there are strong indications for the twin-prime conjecture to be true, hence it is generally accepted. And the approach to find a larger twin prime if one has a given twin-prime is so obvious that it surely has been extensively studied. If such approaches could prove the twin-prime conjecture in any way, I am pretty sure that it would have been solved.

Comment: Any multiple of 12 greater than 24 can be written as the sum of two twin pairs, making it the twin prime equivalent of the Goldbach conjecture.