# Iterated Twin Prime conjecture

Tags: prime-numbers, twin-primes

Here is the beginning of the list of sums of twin prime pairs ([OEIS A054735](https://oeis.org/A054735)):
8, 12, 24, 36, 60, 84, 120, 144, 204, 216, 276, 300, 360, 384, 396, 456, 480, 540, 564, 624, 696, 840, 864, 924,...

"**Conjecture**. The sum of a twin prime pair greater than or equal to 24 can be expressed as the sum of two twin prime pairs."

Examples:

- 24 = 12 + 12
- 36 = 12 + 24
- 60 = 24 + 36
- 84 = 24 + 60
- 120 = 36 + 84 = 60 + 60
- 144 = 24 + 120 = 60 + 84
- 204 = 60 + 144 = 84 + 120
- ...

to be more precise:

- (11+13) = 24 = 12 + 12 = (5+7) + (5+7)
- (17+19) = 36 = 12 + 24 = (5+7) + (11+13)
- (29+31) = 60 = 24 + 36 = (11+13) + (17+19)
- (41+43) = 84 = 24 + 60 = (11+13) + (29+31)
- (59+61) = 120 = 36 + 84 = (17+19) + (41+43)  = 60 + 60 = (29+31) + (29+31)
- ...

Is it always true or are there counterexamples? Is it a known conjecture?

There are no exceptions it works for all sum of twin prime pairs less than 19.999.944.

For example, for (197,199)

15-th 396

- 396=12+384
- 396=36+360
- 396=120+276

Further details can be found in our post: https://bhaxor.blog.hu/2019/03/03/batf41_haxor_stream_conjecture

I would like to know whether is it a known observation? Is it true for all sum of twin prime pairs greater than or equal to 24? I am curious for your opinion.

(When I was trying to check these I found the post: [Twin primes sums conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544221/twin-primes-sums-conjecture/3134545#3134545) that contains a similar conjecture. My question originally was posted as a comment to this.)

Comment: How is "$120=36+84$" a sum of twin-prime pairs ?

Comment: @Peter I believe this is due to $120 = 59 + 61$, $36 = 17 + 19$ and $84 = 41 + 43$.

Comment: @Peter What he fails to mention is that $36=17+19$ and $84=41+43$

Comment: (11+13) = 24 = 12 + 12 = (5+7) + (5+7), 
(17+19) = 36 = 12 + 24 = (5+7) + (11+13),     
(29+31) = 60 = 24 + 36 = (11+13) + (17+19) and so on

Comment: Yes, @John Omielan: (59+61) = 120 = 36 + 84 = (17+19) + (41+43)  = 60 + 60 = (29+31) + (29+31)

Comment: No, @Hagen von Eitzen, because
(17+19) = 36 = 12 + 24 = (5+7) + (11+13)

Comment: and (41+43) = 84 = 24 + 60 = (11+13) + (29+31)

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324673/bátf41-haxor-stream-conjecture-the-sum-of-a-twin-prime-pair

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, this was copied, but there the last link was wrong, sorry. And thanks, the MO question has already corrected.

Comment: At @GerryMyerson's suggestion, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324673/iterated-twin-prime-conjecture?fbclid=IwAR2SqcJPmNIhyFVpNNR5a_BAAtQtQQ5Xg8HpX_MgcCHIDI0_J0NsLUXG8uA#comment810653_324673 , I have changed the title to "Iterated Twin Prime conjecture".

Comment: Since all sums $\ge 12$ of twin primes are divisible by 12, it's convenient to divide by 12. The resulting sequence is https://oeis.org/A002822: 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 12, 17, 18, 23, 25, 30, 32, 33, 38, 40, 45, 47, 52, 58, 70, 72, 77, 87, 95, 100, 103,...

Answer (score 2):

It is a already known observation. It seems is not only true for the sum of a twin pair but any multiple of 12 greater than 24 can be written as the sum of two twin pairs, making it the twin prime equivalent of the Goldbach conjecture. I also verified this up to 100 million.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283906626_A_Twin_Prime_Analog_of_Goldbach%27s_Conjecture